# Custom jQuery functions called from inline events

Tags: jquery, inline, function-call

I want to wrap the following code into a function *using jQuery* and call that function from inline (eg: onclick, onchange etc.).

```
function some_function() {
   alert("Hello world");
}
```

Called by (example):

```
<input type="button" id="message" onclick="some_function()" />
```

---

This question is simple for a reason. I can't seem to find a proper jQuery how-to.

- Should I wrap that function into a
  jQuery *$(document).ready()* ?
- Should make a normal javascript
  function and use
  *$(document).ready()* **in** that function?

Comment: The reason why you don't find how-tos explaining how to do it is because inline events are not the best way to do event handling, and jQuery has made the cross browser compatibility reason obsolete.

Answer (score 1):

You should **not** use that inline event handler to go with jQuery.

Use unobtrusive code:

```
function some_function() {
  alert("Hello world");
}

$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#message').click(some_function);
});
```